# Find out page referrer when the page was opened in a new tab vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url, redirect, referrer

I have an Item page that is often linked to from a site other than ours. For this example we'll say that our site is www.mysite.com and the site that is linking to our page is www.notoursite.com.

We record those occurrences in our database for our clients to look at. We give them a specific url to link to so we can record that number but more often than not our customers do not use that url to link to our page. So I used Request.UrlReferrer to see if the page that linked to the Item page was from www.mysite.com or if it was from www.notoursite.com. If it's www.notoursite.com we then put it in the database.

Now my problem is coming from the way they're linking from www.notoursite.com to www.mysite.com. They're having our site open up in a new tab/window. This is causing the Request.UrlReferrer to show up blank which means it isn't recording the link in our database.

Does anyone know how I could get the referrer when it does this? Let me know if I need to explain anything further.

Comment: Have you tried UrlReferrer property? [check this out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)  Are there any tags in the referral link?  I would always use a query string that gets passed to your website, `www.mysite.com?referrerId=NoTour`  My reasoning is I've been here and not all browsers report the referring url, by creating a query string they put in their links, you're almost guaranteed to get that info.

Comment: UrlReferrer is what we're currently using, but it doesn't catch the referrer if the link was opened in a new tab/window. We had a link set up for them to use but we can't get them to use it. I'm now trying to figure out a way to catch the ones who didn't cooperate with us.

Comment: I'm drawing blanks and it stinks they won't cooperate and just use a query string?  Is your link part of an image or have a script?  There are other ways... but they involve adding more to the referrer's website, not less.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. I guess I'll have to see if our marketing department can get these guys to cooperate because there doesn't seem to be a way to collect the link information otherwise.

Comment: As an alternative, you could make it so if the referrer is null or ""(or same with query string!) it provides them a dropdown that has a list of potential list of the websites that referred them, with an other option and a textbox to type in URLs that may not be on your list.